# Test with expected exception. Getting InvocationTargetException

Tags: unit-testing, reflection, junit

I need to Test some private method that throw an exception. As it is private method I use reflection to invoke it. When I run the test I get InvocationTargetException(this is probably because my method throws exception) and my test fail. But I need my test finish well when my exception from my method has been thrown. I'm not sure if it is clear but here is the sample pseudo-code:

```
@Test(expected=myException.class)
{
    ArgType1 arg1 = new ArgType1();
    ArgType2 arg2 = new ArgType2();

    Class[] args = new Class[2];
    args[0] = ArgType1.class;
    args[1] = ArgType2.class;

    Method method = myClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", args);
    method.invoke(new myClass(), arg1, arg2);
}
```

So, I expect that my test fill finish ok when myMethod() throws myException. But as a result my test fail and I get InvocationTargetException. Please help me to resolve this problem. I'm still looking and can't find the answer.

Comment: To invoke a private method with reflection, you have to make it accessible (_method.setAccessible(true)_) before call it. Anyway, test a private method is not a good testing practice...Theorically, you only have to test public methods, and if you need it, mock private methods.

Comment: Of course I use setAccessible(true) in my oryginal code. So as I understand I sholud mock myClass and give implementation of "myMethod" yes?

Comment: Could you post the original code?